# inline assembly operand constraints

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly

I have the a few questions regarding a piece of code I am trying to understand. I have read [the manual here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C). But it does not seem to explain or answer all of the tricks being used here.

Here is the code:

```
#define SAMPLE_OFFSET1 0
#define SAMPLE_OFFSET2 100
#define SAMPLE_OFFSET1 1000
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s

struct data {
    int m1;
    int m2;
    const uint *m3;
    const uint *m4;
};

#define assembly_function(param1, ... param15) \
... body \
... body \
... body \
... body

void testFunction (data* c, uint *const sample) {
int bat, tmp;
    __asm__ volatile(
        assembly_function("%0", "%q0", "(%4)", "%1", "%w1",
                             "%2", "%q2", "%3", "%b3",
                             "%c6(%5)", "%c7(%5)",
                             STRINGIFY(SAMPLE_OFFSET1),
                             STRINGIFY(SAMPLE_OFFSET2),
                             STRINGIFY(SAMPLE_OFFSET3),
                             "%8")
        : "=&r"(bat), "=&r"(c->m1), "=&r"(c->m2), "=&q"(tmp)
        : "r"(sample), "r"(c),
          "i"(offsetof(data, m3)),
          "i"(offsetof(data, m4)),
          "1"(c->m1), "2"(c->m2)
        : "%rcx", "memory"
    );
}
```

I have wild guesses about the usage of some of the following constraints/options. But I feel its better to confirm from other fellows (or get link to some detailed manual).

- %c in "%c6(%5)" and "%c7(%5)"
- %q in "%q0" and "%q2",
- %b in "%b3"
- %w in "%w1"
- parentheses in "(%4)"
- "i" for two of the input parameters.
- "1" and "2" for two of the input parameters.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stay away from tricks. Stick to plain and simple. Things can get tricky enough anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` forces output as a constant address, here it is used to get rid of the `$` normally emitted in at&t syntax mode for immediates (that the `i` constraint implies).

The `%b`, `%w`, `%l` and `%q` are size override modifiers, they force the appropriate sized register (that is byte, word, long or quad) for the operand.

The parentheses are just part of your everyday at&t style effective address syntax.

`i` is an immediate integer operand (one with constant value).

`"1"` and `"2"` are matching constraints, that is place them in the same location as the indicated other operands.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regarding %c, would be it correct to understand that "%c6(%5)" == sum of the values of %5 and %6 and use this as an constant address in the memory from where we can only read but cannot write?

Comment: No, the address is constant not the value. It's a `foo* const` not a `const foo*`.